# How to optimize this redundant code?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

how can I make the following Code shorter? I am in the middle of my js-journey.
Please ignore the rest of this introduction text, it is just some few more words to make my post longer, since stackoverflow nags of how few my explanation and how much my code ist. just ignore and get your hands dirty with the code...

```js
function showAllJobs() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.remove("hide-section");
}
function showJob_01() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_02() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_03() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_04() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_05() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_06() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.add("hide-section");
}
function showJob_07() {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.add("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.remove("hide-section");
}
```

Comment: I think you should ask it in code review

Comment: You can instead write a function which will remove/add based on what argument(<id of section>) you give.

Comment: Please move it code review.

Comment: as i am new to this platform i dont know about the code review, can someone please give me a link or something?

Comment: @jeyy https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a hideJobs(job) function instead and hide the job given as parameter. something like this:

```js
function hideJobs(job) {
    document.getElementById("section-01").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-02").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-03").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-04").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-05").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-06").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-07").classList.remove("hide-section");
    document.getElementById("section-" + job).classList.add("hide-section");
}
```

Comment: This is how a button looks like, how can I make it pass a "01", "02" etc?

<a onclick="showJob_02()">Job</a>

Comment: Maybe like this?

<a onclick="showJob_02(02)">Job</a>

Comment: ` <a onclick="showJob_02('02')">Job</a>` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the page source and use a library, you can loop over the ids:

```
function showAllJobs() {
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 7; ++ i)
       document.getElementById("section-0"+i).classList.remove("hide-section");
}

function showJob(jobNumber) {
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 7; ++ i)
       if ( i == jobNumber )
           document.getElementById("section-0"+i).classList.remove("hide-section");
       else
           document.getElementById("section-0"+i).classList.add("hide-section");
}
```

This is still rather brittle in terms of the number of sections.

If you can change the source to add a class, say 'section', to all the section things then use something like jQuery

```
function showAllJobs() { $('.section').show(); }
function showJob(id) {
    $('.section').not(id).hide();
    $(id).show();
}
```

For your buttons, you can also use `this` to get the information

```
<button onclick="showJob" href="#section-06">Job 06</button>

function showJob(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.section').not(id).hide();
    $(id).show();
}
```